# Using JS packages without npm or yarn

Tags: reactjs, package.json

I am using react by simply including these two lines of code:

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
```

Now I want to include a JS package ([React Select](https://react-select.com/home)) on my site.
I want a minimal setup, so I do not want to use any package managers like npm or yarn (let alone webpack).

Is it somehow possible to include JS packages without using npm or yarn?

Comment: Yes, the same way you use react.development and react dom. Just take the script and include it were you included these 2.

Answer (score 1):

You can include this and other libraries in the same way, just search for them on cdnjs or unpkg

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-select@2.0.0/dist/react-select.js"></script>
```

make sure to put it after your react links

---

edit: this lib depends on other libs to work, got it working by including these two

```
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/emotion@9.0.0-0/dist/emotion.umd.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.7.2/prop-types.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-select@2.0.0/dist/react-select.js"></script>
```

Comment: That looks really easy, but when I want to use it in my jsx code ("<Select />") I get "ReferenceError: Select is not defined".

Comment: This looks really great. My current problem is that react-select v2 is too old for my react version, so I have to use v3. I found these dependencies `<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/emotion@10.0.9/dist/emotion.umd.min.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/prop-types@15.7.2/prop-types.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/memoize-one@5.0.0/dist/memoize-one.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-select@3.0.8/dist/react-select.esm.js"></script>` But I do not know if I should use `react-select.esm.js` or the cjs version.

Comment: it looks like they dropped support for umd modules for react-select in v3 https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3585 and I couldn't find an easy way to include it in script tag